# Why does replace() function turn my dataframe into an atomic vector?

Tags: r, vector, replace, atomic

I have this code:

```
s12 <- replace(s12$nautos, s12$nautos == 11, 1) # this one does not produce error
s12 <- replace(s12$nautos, s12$nautos == 22, 2) # this one produces error that I cannot use $ because s12 is an atomic vector
```

Running them both again produces the error for both.

When I look at the global environment, s12 dataframe is now a vector.

Why did this happen?

column nautos is a column with 3000 values that takes any number, but all answers are 0-4 except for two entries that are 11 and 22, which I assume are typos and meant to be 1 and 2.

Comment: After you run the first step, you are assigning your data.frame `s12` with a vector from `replace` because you extracted the column 'nautos` i..e there is no longer `nautos` column.  Instead you may have to assign it to same column i.e. `s12$nautos <-`

Comment: If there are more values to be replaced.  Create a key/val dataset and join i.e. `library(data.table);keydat <- data.table(nautos = c(11, 12), val = c(1, 2)); setDT(s12)[keydat, nautos := fcoalesce(val, nautos), on = .(nautos)]`

Comment: @akrun that did it